# How can I redirect a URL to change the host part only in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect one site to another site in a way that other parts of URL remain unchanged. For example: http://abc.com/test1/doc1.aspx redirects to http://xyz.com/test1/doc1.aspx

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better idea is to change DNS records if possible in order to avoid excessive redirects.

If you really want to redirect everything just add this to your web.config in the root folder

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://xyz.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Don't do a permanent redirect, unless you really, truly mean it to be permanent. `301 Moved Permanently` means just that, per the HTTP Standard. Modern standards-compliant browsers cache 301s. Once cached, the original URI is never again hit. That means that if you decide to 'undo' your 301, clients who have already been redirected will *never* find out about it. Firefox, Chrome, etc, allow the user to clear the 301 cache, but newer versions of IE, in particular, make it very hard to clear the 301 redirect cache. Don't use a 301 unless you really trulyl want it to be permanent.

Comment: Thanks. This seem to worked not sure what will be the bad side of this. But for now it is doing the job.

Comment: @araza85 - if you find the answer useful, please mark it as answer for other readers.

Comment: @NicholasCarey - yes, agree on what you said on permanent redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the host from the first url with the expected new host as shown below

```
string currentUrl = "http://abc.com/test1/doc1.aspx";
Uri uri = new Uri(currentUrl);

//Result: "http://xyz.com/test1/doc1.aspx"
string newUrl = currentUrl.Replace(uri.Host, "xyz.com");
Response.Redirect(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You transform a URI like this:

```
private RedirectToNewHost( Uri uri , string newHost )
{
  UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder( uri ) ;
  builder.Host = newHost ;
  Response.Redirect(builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}

private RedirectToNewHost( string uri , string newHost )
{
  UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder( uri ) ;
  builder.Host = newHost ;
  Response.Redirect( builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri );
}
```

But as @Dragan_Radivojevic pointed out, modifying DNS so that the old domain name is an alias for the new domain is a clean solution. Then, if you've changing domain names, have the web server look at the inbound URI and pop up an informative message that the domain name has changed and they should start using the new domain name.